# Random generator with no duplicated numbers

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array that needs to hold 6 randomly generated numbers. What I have done to achieve ***no duplicates*** is used the following code. I thought this would work by adding 1 to the duplicate but then again it will again show up towards the end!

```
userInput = document.getElementById('txtGen').value;
var numbers = new Array(6);
var msg = '';

for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
{
    numbers[i] = Math.random() * userInput;
    numbers[i] = Math.floor(numbers[i]);
    if(numbers[i] == numbers[i-1]){
        numbers[i] = numbers[i++];  
    }
    msg += '<input id="num' + i + '"' + 'type="text" value="' + numbers[i] + '" />';

}


document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = msg;
```

**I also tried this**, but that also didn't work!

```
for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
{
    numbers[i] = Math.random() * userInput;
    numbers[i] = Math.floor(numbers[i]);
    for(var b=0;b<numbers.length;b++)
    {
        if(numbers[b] == numbers[b--]){
            numbers[b] = numbers[b++];  
        }
    }
    msg += '<input id="num' + i + '"' + 'type="text" value="' + numbers[i] + '" />';

}
```

Comment: `numbers[i] = numbers[i++];` has no effect else but `i` increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` to check if the number is already in the array. And if it is, you can generate a new number.

```
var userInput = document.getElementById('txtGen').value;
var numbers = new Array(6);
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    var temp = 0;
    do
    {
        temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * userInput);
    }
    while (numbers.indexOf(temp) > -1)

    numbers[i] = temp;
}

document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = numbers.join(); // <- Write numbers to div.
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it didn't seem to show up anything! Did you post this up for me to try and replace it?

Comment: This code just fills the array, it doesn't output anything. You still need to do something with the values in the array.

Comment: Hi, I still am having troubles implementing this to make it work :\ @Jerodev

Comment: What exactly do you need to do with the numbers?

Comment: Oh sorry, I am running them through a loop which assigns them to an input value. The reason I am doing this is because apart of my assignment needs me to generate 'lucky tattsoloto numbers' inbetween the 'user input' specified.

The <inputs ... /> are being put into a div

Comment: <h4>Your Lucky Numbers are: </h4><div id="numbers"></div>

Comment: I have added a line that shows the numbers in the div. The rest is up to you. ;)

Comment: Sick cheers for that, I should've been able to figure that one out.. -_- tiredness getting the better of me.

Answer (score 0):

```
userInput = document.getElementById('txtGen').value;
var numbers = new Array(6),tempNo=new Array(6);
var msg = '';

for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
{
    tempNo[i] = Math.random() * userInput;
    if(!numbers[tempNo[i]]){
        numbers[Math.floor(tempNo[i])] = Math.floor(tempNo[i]);
        msg += '<input id="num' + i + '"' + 'type="text" value="' + Math.floor(tempNo[i]) + '" />';
    }

}

document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = msg;
```

try this with associative array

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution...

```
for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
{
    numbers[i] = Math.random() * userInput;
    numbers[i] = Math.floor(numbers[i]);
    for(var b=1;b<numbers.length;b++)
    {
        if(numbers[b] == numbers[b--]){
            numbers[b] = Math.random() * userInput;
            numbers[b] = Math.floor(numbers[b]);
            b=1;
        }
    }
    msg += '<input id="num' + i + '"' + 'type="text" value="' + numbers[i] + '" />';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var output =document.getElementById('numbers'),
    numbers = new Array(6),
    msg = '';

for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){  
    numbers[i] = randomNumber()
    msg += '<input id="num' + i + '"' + 'type="text" value="' + numbers[i] + '" />';
}

function randomNumber(max){
  max = (max > 0) ? max : 100; 
  var a = 1 + max*(Math.random());
  return Math.round(a);  
}


output.innerHTML = msg;
```

```html
<div id="numbers"></div>
```